# IE - Custom fonts not loading over HTTPS

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, https, sharepoint-2013, font-face

- Custom fonts work while navigating through **inner links**, but are **not**
  loading while **refreshing**.
- **Cache** is handled but still doesn't work.
- Works with **CDN**, but CDN cannot be used.

Custom fonts: bootstrap glyphicon

Note: **SharePoint 2013 project**

---

Custom font is declared like this 
Css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

Comment: How do you link to the stylesheet in the page?

Comment: The css which has the font-face is the first one to linked. bootstrap css jquery ui css comes later

Comment: Please provide the exact HTML fragment you used to link to it.

Comment: This is how its in the master page    
    `<link href="../../_layouts/15/DAP/Styles/customStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />`